# Dialog width not proper

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

In my application i am using a dialog fragment to display a dialog.I code is working fine but the width is dialog is very small.My dialog looks like this

[image]

I want the width of the dialog to be more but its not happening

Code

```
public class MyResourceDialog extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_resource_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here add this code to your `DialogFragment`'s Subclass

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);

    super.onResume();
}
```

This code will resize your `DialogFragment` on the `onResume()` event.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ya thanks it worked ,but sir can you explain me something on it

Comment: This code is setting width and height attributes on Your DialogFragment's class to 'MATCH_PARENT', which means that they will have same width and height as their Parent (Which in your Application's case is Full Screen).